# How to use HDF5 tables in Fortran

Tags: fortran, hdf5

I'd like to use [HDF5 Tables](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/HL/RM_H5TB.html) in Fortran, but I'm having some trouble. An example would be useful, but only C examples are [provided](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/h5table.html).

Part of my problem is how to handle the offsets and sizes it needs. With gfortran, I may be able to use [sizeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIZEOF.html) and [loc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/LOC.html), but those are gfortran specific extensions. I see that newer versions of Fortran have c_loc and c_sizeof which may help, but perhaps they only work on c variables?

I also have no idea what chunk_size should be.

FWIW, the ugly code below uses loc and sizeof. It compiles and runs but gives an error (and doesn't put anything in the hdf5 file):

```
 size:                    8
 offsets:                    0                    4
 types:           0           0
 initialized
 file open
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.8) thread 140636908803840:
  #000: ../../../src/H5Tcompound.c line 370 in H5Tinsert(): not a datatype
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
 table created
```

So the offsets could make sense, but the types don't really.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
module tdef
  type blarg
    integer :: arg
    real    :: blah
  end type
end

PROGRAM H5_TABLE

  use tdef
  USE HDF5
  use h5lt
  use h5tb

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER(HID_T) :: file_id
  INTEGER     ::   error
  integer(HSIZE_T) :: nfields, nrecords
  integer(SIZE_T)  :: type_size
  type(blarg) :: test
  character(len=4), dimension(2) :: field_names = (/' arg', 'blah'/)
  integer(SIZE_T), dimension(2) :: field_offset
  integer(HID_T), dimension(2) :: field_types
  integer(HSIZE_T) ::  chunk_size = 1
  integer :: compress = 0

  nfields  = 2
  nrecords = 2

  type_size = sizeof(test)
  print *, "size:", type_size

  field_offset(1) = loc(test%arg) - loc(test)
  field_offset(2) = loc(test%blah) - loc(test)
  print *, "offsets:", field_offset

  field_types(1) = H5T_NATIVE_INTEGER
  field_types(2) = H5T_NATIVE_REAL
  print *, "types:", field_types

  CALL h5open_f(error)
  print *, "initialized"

  CALL h5fcreate_f("cpt.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F, file_id, error)
  print *, "file open"

  call h5tbmake_table_f('Table Title', file_id, "Steps", nfields, &
            nrecords, type_size, field_names, field_offset, &
            field_types, chunk_size, compress, error) 
  print *, "table created"

  CALL h5fclose_f(file_id, error)

  CALL h5close_f(error)

END PROGRAM H5_TABLE
```

Comment: The offsets look OK. `C_loc` wouldn't help you, because it returns `type(c_ptr)` and you cannot make pointer arithmetic with it (without additional `transfer`). I played with your program a bit, but I don't know HDF5 enough to spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Your comment about c_loc helps clears up [this](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Fortran/comp.lang.fortran/2009-01/msg00104.html) for me; now I understand why the author used transfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this is a pretty simple problem.

I call h5open_f after using H5T_NATIVE_INTEGER and H5T_NATIVE_REAL. However, those two aren't assigned the appropriate values until after h5open_f is called. Calling h5open_f first solves my problem.